# Stack ghci with library

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a C++ library bundled with (and called from) a Haskell library. I'm using a custom build with a `cabal`, `Makefile`, and `Setup.hs` files almost identical to those described [here](http://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-04-18/haskell_and_cpp). I also want to use GHCi, so my `Makefile` creates a dynamic (`.so`) library in addition to the static (`.a`) library.

> **Note:** I think GHCi must use dynamic libraries; if I'm wrong about this then maybe there is an easier solution.

I can make GHCi work in this environment by passing an explicit path to the .so file. This post is about how to make `stack ghci` work. The main error this produces is `cannot find libfoo.so` (due to adding `extra-libraries: foo` in the cabal file). Using -v reveals that stack is not looking in the "extra-lib-dirs" paths that I modified in the Setup.hs script (<s>[possible bug](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1656)</s> [bug](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/970)). `stack ghci` **does** look for libraries in the "extra-lib-dirs" that are specified in the cabal file. Unfortunately, due to a [cabal bug](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1317), I cannot specify a *relative* path for extra-lib-dirs: it causes both `cabal configure` and `stack build` to fail with the same error.

I don't want to install my C++ library system-wide (which would resolve the issue by allowing me to use an absolute path in extra-lib-dirs).

Concrete questions:

1. Do I need a `.so` file to use GHCi?
2. How can I tell `stack ghci` where to look for a library in a *relative* path?

Comment: Can you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to solve the problem?

Comment: @ErikR Sounds reasonable, but apparently not. When I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, `stack ghci` does not look there for libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37643200/925978) shows a cleaner way to include a C++ library with a Haskell library that does not require the use of `extra-libraries` or relative paths. The idea is to let cabal do all the heavy lifting instead of using a custom build-type.

`stack ghci` works (with some caveats on build order due to a [GHC bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12152)).